# Como realizar validaciones sin necesidad de usar Switch en C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Hay alguna forma de realizar validaciones en C# sin necesidad de utilizar switch
Ejemplo

```
var tipoDocumentoFormateado = "";

switch(tipoDocumento){
    case "Cedula de ciudadania":{
        tipoDocumentoFormateado = "CC";
        breack;
    }
    case "Targeta de identidad" : {
       tipoDocumentoFormateado = "TI";
       breack;
    }
    ....
}
```

A algo parecido a como se puede hacer en JavaScript:

```
let tiposDocumentos = {
    "Cedula de ciudadania" : "CC",
    "Targeta de identidad" : "TI"
    .....
}

let tipoDocumentoFormateado = tiposDocumento[tipoDocumento];
```

Answer (score 2):

Eso se puede lograr usando un diccionario:

```
 var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 dict.Add("key1", "value1");
 dict.Add("key2", "value2");
 dict.Add("key3", "value3");
 Console.WriteLine(dict["key1"]);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, llevo rato investigando y no encontraba respuesta  ya que no sabia que preguntar, lo único que se me ocurría era Arreglos con índices literales en C# 